# Calling x.php file from a Javascript file

Tags: javascript, php, pdf

I am working on a quite big eWeb tool which includes lots of `.js` & `.php` files and this tool is developed by someone else that I can not reach.

Assume that a customer buys some stuff and at the end, as a seller, I am supposed to confirm the customer's shopping by clicking the 'confirm order' button in some table.  Now, I want to print a PDF file (which is either located in my local disk or on the server of the eWeb tool depends on the difficulty) when I click the confirm button.  I can reach the printer and print the PDF file by following PHP code in my localhost when I directly call it:

```
<?php
    $printer ="HP Officejet Pro X476dw MFP PCL 6 (Network)";
    $path = "C:/Test_PDF/TestPDF.pdf";
    $fileName = "TestPDF.pdf";`

    if($ph = printer_open($printer)) { 
        $filecontents = file_get_contents($path);
        printer_set_option($ph, PRINTER_MODE, "RAW"); 
        printer_write($ph, $filecontents);
        printer_close($ph);
    }
?>
```

Now, what I want is to print the PDF file also from the web tool when I click the 'confirm order' button! I do not want to load the PDF file in a hidden iframe or embed it somewhere because, as I said before, the tool is quite big and I do not want to cause any problem somewhere else for now.

Can anybody give me some ideas about the solutions please?

Comment: You can't send orders to a client printer. If it works in localhost is relative normal, but a client under http server client decides. you can call to print() javascript function that opens the browser's dialog to print, but you can't connect to a remote printer and send it custom orders because this will be a major security bug.

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude 

Only one person (who confirms the orders) is using this tool and he uses the same computer all the time. Customers can not reach the tool that I mentioned.

Comment: Is in localhost too?

Comment: What do you mean by saying 'Is in localhost too?' ? 

For testing I have used that php code in my localhost and when I call it, it does what I want. But the tool is of course on another domain.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that PHP is a server-side language, as some people said before, you can't send a print request to a client. The request is originated in the server, so...

What you can do:

**1.- Load the pdf in the webpage.**

**2.- Handle the body onLoad as follows:**

```
<body onload="window.print();">
```

That way the client will use it's printer if any.

I know that you don't want to load the pdf in a webpage but... This seems like the only solution.

**P.D.: I'm not sure if you want to print the receipt for the customer or the seller. Explain yourself better and I will try to help you :)**

Comment: It is not the client who will print the pdf file. The client just makes the order on the web, then I (as admin) log in the system and confirm the customers' orders. What I want is: print also a pdf file directly when I confirm the order by clicking the button.

Comment: Assume that you have a eCommerce web page called abc.com and customers makes some orders over there. After the customer finishes his/her order, you are, as seller, logging in the admin system (lets call it 'service.abc.com') and from there you can see all the information of the customer and his/her orders in a form. Then, you are supposed to confirm the customers' orders by clicking 'Confirm' button. What I want is to also trigger a print function when I click 'Confirm' button. This trigger should print a pdf file (always the same file) by sending the file to my local printer.

Comment: The same code above applies to you because, although you are the admin, the host is somewhere else. Right? If you don't want to make it complex, just add a link after the confirmation to the pdf with the hints I gave you.